# How to retrieve HREF attribute value from a link?

Tags: jquery, jplayer

There is  element on the page

```
<a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="playDialog" data-dialog-title="Audio" href="/Home/Play/id?media/track.mp3">Play Audio</a>
```

When user clicks on it then model dialog created, jPlayer created inside of this dialog
on  <...>
in document ready function
How i can retrieve href value from the source  element? 
In other words I want to get this value and pass this filename to the player.
May be other better ways exist? ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
// here
                var fname1 = $(this).attr("title");
                console.log('** title=' + fname1);

                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: fname1
                }).jPlayer("play"); 
            },
            ended: function (event) {
                $(this).jPlayer("play");
            },
            swfPath: "swf",
            supplied: "mp3"
        })
    .bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function () { // pause other instances of player when current one play
        $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
    });
  });
```

Example, I have elements on one page

```
<br/>
<a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="playDialog1" data-dialog-title="Audio1" href="/Home/Play/id?media/track.mp3">Play Audio</a>
<br/>
<a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="playDialog2" data-dialog-title="Audio2" href="/Home/Play/id?media/track1.mp3">Play Audio1</a>
```

And when user clicks this link I create model dialog this player. The question is how to get href or title from the source link inside of this script, which creates player.

Or another question: how I can get title of player's dialog? then I can retrieve from what link I creeated the dialog

Comment: are you using jQuery-UI dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

you can use de .attr() function on jquery to get the atributes values ex:

```
    $('.openDialog').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var href = $(this).attr('href')
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {

                console.log('** title=' + fname1);

                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: href
                }).jPlayer("play"); 
            },
            ended: function (event) {
                $(this).jPlayer("play");
            },
            swfPath: "swf",
            supplied: "mp3"
        })
    .bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function () { // pause other instances of player when current one play
        $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
    });
});
```